# Chrome and Apple iphone emoticons in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, emoticons

I am displaying strings in javascript/html that have Apple iphone emoticons. Safari handles them. Chrome doesn't. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62435) with Chrome, as it does not natively support emoticons for some versions (though the most listed is OSX Lion, I'm pretty sure it doesn't support Emoji on most versions). Users can use a plugin to display them, but you're sort of helpless on your end. You can parse and remove them, or swap them out for a set of emoticons that you include as a font with your webpage, similar to how forums do it.

Comment: So could I build a map from IOS emojis to unicode ones? Hasn't someone already done that?

Comment: You definitely could. You could also include a font [http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp] of emojis and map it that way. Someone has likely done that, let me look around.